# Read Json with NaN into Python and Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, nan

I understand that NaN is not allowed in JSON files. I usually use

```
import pandas as pd 
pd.read_json('file.json')
```

to read in JSON into python. Looking through the documentation, I do not see an option to handle that value.

I have a JSON file, data.json, that looks like

```
[{"city": "Los Angeles","job":"chef","age":30},
 {"city": "New York","job":"driver","age":35},
 {"city": "San Jose","job":"pilot","age":NaN}]
```

How can I read this into python/pandas and handle the NaN values?

EDIT:

Amazing answer below!! Thanks fixxxer!! Just so it's documented, reading it in from a separate file

```
import pandas as pd
import json

text=open('data.json','r')
x=text.read()

y=json.loads(x)
data=pd.DataFrame(y)
data.head()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read the json file into a variable:

```
x = '''[{"city": "Los Angeles","job":"chef","age":30},  {"city": "New York","job":"driver","age":35},  {"city": "San Jose","job":"pilot","age":NaN}]'''
```

Now, load it with json.loads

```
In [41]: import json

In [42]: y = json.loads(x)

In [43]: y
Out[43]: 
[{u'age': 30, u'city': u'Los Angeles', u'job': u'chef'},
 {u'age': 35, u'city': u'New York', u'job': u'driver'},
 {u'age': nan, u'city': u'San Jose', u'job': u'pilot'}]
```

And,

```
    In [44]: pd.DataFrame(y)
Out[44]: 
   age         city     job
0   30  Los Angeles    chef
1   35     New York  driver
2  NaN     San Jose   pilot
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Just so it's documented, reading in from a file
`import pandas as pd
 import json

text=open('data.json','r')
x=text.read()

y=json.loads(x)

data=pd.DataFrame(y)

data.head()`

Comment: @max In that case, let me make the answer look less-stable. Thanks!

Comment: For me it doesn't works. I have nan in my json file ("threshold" : nan) which raises 'ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded' error.